# Perl logical and with multiple tests

Tags: perl, if-statement, logical-operators

Is it normal to write in such way:

```
if(($x && $y && $z) eq "test"){

}
```

If I am interested in `($x eq "test") && ($y eq "test") && ($z eq "test")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wouldn't be normal because it doesn't even work

`$x && $y` returns either `$x` or `$y` depending on whether the value of `$x` is true or not.

That means that `($x && $y) && $z` returns either `$x`, `$y` or `$z` depending on the values of `$x` and `$y`.

That means that only one of `$x`, `$y` or `$z` will be compared against `'test'`.

For example, you'll get a false positive (returns true when it should return false) when you have `$x='abc'; $y='def'; $z='test';`.

If you wanted something shorter, then you'd have to use something like

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( all );

if ( all { $_ eq "test" } $x, $y, $z )
```

Comment: mob understood my question correctly, thanks!

In real code it worked as I wanted, but now I understand it is incorrect.

Comment: ok, I'll try to formulate my question again (sorry:)). I've needed a check that at list one of them is null or (if needed later) eq to some specific string. Code (($x && $y && $z) eq "") always was false in my tests (if something was empty), and I thought everything is ok. So, the best way is use List::MoreUtils qw( all ) ?

Comment: no, a shorter equivalent of ($x eq "") && ($y eq "") && ($z eq "") or ($x eq "test") && ($y eq "test") && ($z eq "test")?

Comment: thanks for your patience and will to help:)

I can't tell you if I was mistaken or not because I am still a bit confused:)

This was not my code, I always wrote in such situations: if ($x eq 'test' && $y eq 'test' && $z eq 'test') 

And this logic was needed in this context.

But I saw this code, tested it, and always got false in this expression when one or more of them was empty:)

Maybe I was wrong in testing or ff cached my edits again:)

Comment: p.s. the original code was

if(($x && $y && $z) eq ""){

}

Comment: if(($x && $y && $z) eq ""){ }

I've put some misunderstanding when I wrote "test". Originally it was 
if(($x && $y && $z) eq ""){ }. This code always returns false if one of vars is empty, or not?

Comment: Again, if the question is wrong, fix the question (and let me know).

Comment: Incidentally, core's `List::Util` module now has the same `all` function, and it will appear in core from perl 5.20.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The expression `$x && $y && $z` is equivalent to the expression

```
$x ? $x : $y ? $y : $z
```

and will be evaluated separately from the expression on the other side of the `eq` operator.

Writing `if ($x eq 'test' && $y eq 'test' && $z eq 'test') ...` as you do is as reasonably terse as you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

As an elaboration on [ikegami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22749600/725418), I thought I would show the code for the `all()` subroutine, as it is rather simple, and gives a good demonstration of the logic behind the answer to the question. And also, as it happens, makes a good demonstration for how [prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) work.

```
sub all (&@) {
    my $f = shift;
    foreach ( @_ ) {
        return NO unless $f->();
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The prototypes `&` and `@` refer to a code reference, and a list of arguments. `YES` and `NO` are constants for true and false defined as follows:

```
# Use pure scalar boolean return values for compatibility with XS
use constant YES => ! 0;
use constant NO  => ! 1;
```

The basic gist of this subroutine is to take a code reference (an anonymous subroutine) and execute it once for each argument, using `$_` as the loop variable. If any argument causes the code block to return a false value, the subroutine returns false and ends.

With this code and these prototypes we can use the `all` subroutine much like [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), with a code block first:

```
all { $_ eq "foo" } "foo", "bar", "baz";
```

If we remove the prototypes `(&@)`, we must pass the code reference as a standalone, as part of the list:

```
all sub { $_ eq "foo" }, "foo", "bar", "baz";
```

Note the addition of the `sub` keyword, and the comma after the code block.

Comment: Thx. Useful and Impressive.